# MySQL Updating multiple rows with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

My table carts

| cart_id | mem_id | uid | cart_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhkwag970 | null | 110 |
| 2 | jhkwag970 | null | 60 |

What I am trying to do is update those 2 rows' cart_price at once. But, each cart_price are subtracted with difference value.

I have tried

```
 update carts
 set cart_price = (select salePrice from(
 select (cart_price-round((cart_price / (select (sum(cart_price)) from carts where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null )) * 168)) as salePrice
 from carts
 where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null
) A)
where cart_id in
(select cId from(select cart_id as cId
 from carts
 where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null) B );
```

the result that I wanted is each cart_price is being subtracted (110-109=1 and 60-59 =1)

| cart_id | mem_id | uid | cart_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhkwag970 | null | 1 |
| 2 | jhkwag970 | null | 1 |

I know that problem occurs in set = (select ...) clause. SQL show output that 1242 subquery returns more than 1 rows.
So, I tried

```
update carts
 set cart_price = (select salePrice from(
 select cart_id, (cart_price-round((cart_price / (select (sum(cart_price)) from carts where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null )) * 168)) as salePrice
 from carts
 where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null
) A where A.cart_id = B.cId)
where cart_id in
(select cId from(select cart_id as cId
 from carts
 where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null) B );
```

to Match cId of where clause and Set Clause, but returns B.cId is unknown error.

Comment: No, the result of the cart_price is 1. I want to reduce the original cart_price to  subquery which is cart_price/(sum of cart_price) * 168

Comment: can you please add the sale price table as well

Comment: salePrice is not table it is alias name of (cart_price-round((cart_price / (select (sum(cart_price))  clause , I added because mysql cannot update its own table using subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a bit overcomplicated. Try

```
update carts c
join (
  select cart_id, cart_price - round(cart_price /(
      select sum(c.cart_price) from carts c where c.mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and c.uid is null) * 168) v
  from carts
  where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and uid is null
  ) A on c.cart_id = A.cart_id
set c.cart_price = A.v;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I should match the cart_id with the update clause's cart_id. So, answer should be

```
 update carts c
 set cart_price = (select salePrice from(
 select cart_id, (cart_price-round((cart_price / (select (sum(cart_price)) from carts where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null )) * 168)) as salePrice
 from carts 
 where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null
) A where A.cart_id = c.cart_id)
where cart_id in
(select cId from(select cart_id as cId
 from carts
 where mem_id = 'jhkwag970' and cart_imp_uid is null) B );
```